# How to find a control via JavaScript and get the ClientID

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have the following aspx code:

```
<div id="IsAccountingOk" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Luk" class="close">X</a><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblIsAccountingOkHeader" runat="server" Text="Kassekladde:" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Der skal først vælges regnskabsår!"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnIsAccountingOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="btnIsAccountingOK_Click"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

but how can I access 'IsAccountingOk' and get it via document.getElementByID?
I have also tried the following with no success :-(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var session = '<%=Session["AccountYearID"] == null%>';
    if (session.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
        document.getElementById('<%= this.FindControl("IsAccountingOk").ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

The following error has occurred:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Objektreferencen er ikke indstillet
>   til en forekomst af et objekt.' (The error message is in danish - but
>   I got a null value from FindControl)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Regards Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div` you're targeting isn't a server-side control, so you just use `id` directly:

```
document.getElementById('IsAccountingOk').style.display = 'block';
```